# Send Email on form submission with IF statement using GAS

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google form that collects data.  it feeds into a spreadsheet.  I am trying to send an email based on the data being submitted.  I have the named values accurate.  I have an IF statement to look at a certain attriubte for a "No".  If the submission has that for a certain field, then an email is shot off.  The error is occuring at the MailApp.sendEmail line:

Exception: The parameters (number[],String,String) don't match the method signature for MailApp.sendEmail.
at sendEmail(Code:26:13)

Not sure what I have mapped incorrectly...

```
function sendEmail(e) {
  var named_values = e.namedValues;
  var name = named_values['Teacher Name'];
  var email = named_values['Teacher Email'];
  var room = named_values['Room'];
  var clco = named_values['Clean and orderly'];
  var clcod = named_values['Details1'];
  var cph = named_values['Cell phone holder'];
  var cphd = named_values['Details2'];
  var mws = named_values['20% max wall space coverage '];
  var mwsd = named_values['Details3'];
  var pwa = named_values['Proper wall adhesives used'];
  var pwad = named_values['Details4'];
  var uf = named_values['No unauthorized furniture or appliances'];
  var ufd = named_values['Details5'];
  var ard = named_values['All Required Displays'];
  var ardd = named_values['Details6'];

  if (clco == 'No')

    var msg = "Hello " + name + ",\n \nAn evaluation of your classroom, " + room + ", was performed by administration.  The following item needs to be addressed: Clean and Orderly Classroom. \n\nDetails for the item are as follows: " + clcod + " \n\nPlease rectify these issues as soon as possible."
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Classroom Expectations", msg)
}
```

Comment: Could you log the email to see what value does it hold?, it may be taking the information from another cell

Comment: `named_values['Teacher Email']` points to an array not a single value often the answer is `named_values['Teacher Email'][0]` [form submit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: including `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` in your script is a handy debug tool that will let you evaluate all the Event Objects including the namedValues.

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose with brackets all the content in your `if` statement. You are not using brackets, so the content of the `if` gets only to be the first line of code after the statement.